# Dynamic Dropdown in Angularjs with delete function

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a dynamic dropdown which I intend to look like [Image](https://lensdump.com/i/wXMGK.).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ova59e7b/2/)

```
function HelloCntl($scope) {
        $scope.friends = [
          {id:1,name: 'John'},
          {id:2,name: 'Mary'},
          {id:3,name: 'Mike'},
          {id:4,name: 'Adam'},
          {id:5,name: 'Julie'}
        ];
        $scope.selected = $scope.friends[0]; // initialise selection
        $scope.delete = function(x) {
          var y = $scope.friends.indexOf(x);
          $scope.friends.splice(y, 1);
        }
        var index = 6;
        $scope.add = function(x) {
          $scope.friends.push({
            id: index,
            name: x
          });
          index++;
          $scope.new_selected = '';
        }
```

Clicking on John from the dropdown adds john down below(also stores it in an array) as well as deletes it from the dropdown list. Once it is deleted from below, it is added back to the drop down.

As John Mary Adam and Mike are already below (also in the array), they're deleted from the dropdown (Only Julie now remains in the dropdown). Once they're deleted from below, they're added back to the dropdown.
Can anyone help me out with an AngularJS implementation on fiddle?

Comment: show us what you made so far

Comment: @Bart  I've included the fiddle link

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu8nckca/1/)  
I am so bad at this that instead of iimproving it, I totally messed it up.

Rather than showing all the items at first, i need it to use something like ng-click and append the items below as they are added.

Let say if initially I added John it should show only john as an alert(and also hide it from the dropdown), and then if I click Mary, it should show Mary alert below John alert (also while hiding the Mary in dropdown). When the alerts are dismissed, The respective alerts should be added to the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I though my answer to your previous question was good enough to edit. You just need `ng-repeat` to display them all at once. Here is an **old** example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script srt="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HelloCntl">

    <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
      <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="i as i.name for i in friends"></select>
      <div>
        <!-- ADD class="alert alert-info" HERE to wrap all boxes with the blue background -->
        <!-- ng-repeat was added to show all at once -->
        <!-- ng-show was modified to hide already selected name -->
        <div ng-repeat="x in friends" ng-show="friends && x!=selected" class="alert alert-info">Name: {{x.name}} | ID: {{x.id}} <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(x)">X</button></div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('HelloCntl', HelloCntl);

      function HelloCntl($scope) {
        $scope.friends = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'John'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Mary'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Mike'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Adam'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Julie'
          }
        ];
        $scope.selected = $scope.friends[0]; // initialise selection
        $scope.delete = function(x) {
          var y = $scope.friends.indexOf(x);
          $scope.friends.splice(y, 1);
        }
        var index = 6;
        $scope.add = function(x) {
          $scope.friends.push({
            id: index,
            name: x
          });
          index++;
          $scope.new_selected = '';
        }

      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

### Update

I have fixed the logic, to meet what you need. Took some time reading your step-by-step process of adding and removing names from both places, but now it's working as intended. Here is a Snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script srt="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HelloCntl">

    <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
      <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="i as i.name for i in friends"></select>
      <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add(selected)">Add</button>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in selected_friends" ng-show="selected_friends" class="alert alert-info">
          Name: {{x.name}} | ID: {{x.id}}
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(x)">X</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="add_back(x)">Add back</button>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('HelloCntl', HelloCntl);

      function HelloCntl($scope) {
        $scope.selected_friends = [];
        $scope.friends = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'John'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Mary'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Mike'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Adam'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Julie'
          }
        ];
        $scope.selected = $scope.friends[0]; // initialise selection
        $scope.delete = function(x) {
          var y = $scope.selected_friends.indexOf(x);
          $scope.selected_friends.splice(y, 1);
        }
        $scope.delete2 = function(x) {
          var y = $scope.friends.indexOf(x);
          $scope.friends.splice(y, 1);
        }
        var index = 6;
        $scope.add = function(x) {
          if ($scope.selected_friends.indexOf(x) == -1) {
            $scope.delete2(x);
            $scope.selected_friends.push(x);
          }
        }
        $scope.add_back = function(x) {
          $scope.delete(x);
          $scope.friends.push(x);
        }
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu8nckca/1/)  
I am so bad at this that instead of iimproving it, I totally messed it up.  
Rather than showing all the items at first, i need it to use something like ng-click and append the items below as they are added.  
Let say if initially I added John it should show only john as an alert(and also hide it from the dropdown), and then if I click Mary, it should show Mary alert below John alert (also while hiding the Mary in dropdown). When the alerts are dismissed, The respective alerts should be added to the dropdown.

Comment: @dracarys3 I have fixed it, now it should meet your request. It would be messier to read if I would add names to the array (under dropdown)  **once** I select them (needs `ng-change="add(...)"`), so I just added a button instead